# Python. Pascal's triangle

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python. Now I am trying to create an algorithm that will build a Pascal's triangle.

My first step is to create a basic iteration that will use a list called current level and create the next level list based on it as follows:

1. Add 0 to the first number to create the left number and insert it
   into a list.
2. Create the inner row of numbers and insert them into a list
3. Add 0 to the last number to create the right number and insert it
   into a list.

My code includes only one iteration, but iteration is not a problem now. I do not understand how to address the elements of the list by their index correctly.

Can somebody give me a hint?

Thanks!

```
currentlevel = [1]

nextlevel = []
leftnumber = 0 + currentlevel[0]
nextlevel.append(leftnumber)

for item[index] in currentlevel:
    if index > 1 and index < len(currentlevel)-1:
        item[index] = item[index] + item[index+1]
        nextlevel.append(item[index])
    else:
        rightnumber = currentlevel[-1] + 0
        nextlevel.append(rightnumber)

currentlevel = nextlevel
print(currentlevel)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't normally post full answers but...

```
maxlevel = 5
currentlevel = [1]

for levels in range(maxlevel):
    nextlevel = [1]
    for index,item in enumerate(currentlevel[0:-1]):
        if (len(currentlevel) == 1):
            break

        nextlevel.append(item + currentlevel[index + 1])

    nextlevel.append(1)

    print(nextlevel)

    currentlevel = nextlevel
```

Comment: The 0 is redundant in `for levels in range(0,maxlevel):`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This has helped.

Comment: that wasn't quite what I meant, `range(0, maxlevel)` is equivalent to `range(maxllevel)` so you don't need to do the former.  You're now doing 4 loops instead of 5, did you mean to do that?

Comment: Well, I gotta say that I didn't know about the single param range() - great catch. Will fix.

Answer (score 1):

1. This does not work:

   ```
   for item[index] in currentlevel:
   ```

   Use this:

   ```
   for index, item in enumerate(currentlevel):
   ```

   and then wherever you are using `item[index]` use either `item` or `currentlevel[index]`. Except...
2. Except here:

   ```
   item[index] = item[index] + item[index+1]
   nextlevel.append(item[index])
   ```

   Here it would be best if you used another variable:

   ```
   next_item = currentlevel[index] + currentlevel[index+1]
   nextlevel.append(next_item)
   ```

   Although `item` would work, it is slightly confusing; but if you use `currentlevel[index]` where `next_item` is, you'd be destroying the previous row. Not a problem if you want to print-and-forget, but it's nice to have a choice and be flexible.
3. This will skip two elements unnecesarily:

   ```
   if index > 1 and index < len(currentlevel)-1:
   ```

   Remove the first clause:

   ```
   if index < len(currentlevel)-1:
   ```

That's all I see for now, can't test.

EDIT: Not an error as such, but `0 + whatever` is same as `whatever`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing some Python novelty, the line `for item[index] in currentlevel:` is a syntax error (edit: it's not a syntax error but a name error; see Tutleman's comment).

Try the following alternative to get both the list element and its index:

```
for index, item in enumerate(currentlevel):
```

Or use the following one to get just the indexes and access the elements through them:

```
for index in range(len(currentlevel)):
    item = currentlevel[index]
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-python-for-loops) for more information.

Comment: You're right about the `for item[index]` being an error but it's a `NameError`, not a `SyntaxError`. After all, it's perfectly valid to do something like: `x=[1,2,3]; for x[0] in x:`. The behavior of that is really weird (assuming you don't modify the list anywhere else in your loop, at the end, `x` will equal `[3,2,3]`), because you're reassigning the first value of `x` to whatever the next value in `x` is, but you can do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This has helped.